# Spacing Discrepancy

Tags: spacing

I'm trying to create a precise spacing in a document, but am having issues. Despite the fact that I've requested an indent of 1.2cm, the two lines do not line up properly, as expected. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\hangindent1.2cm{Taylor, Herman. \emph{A Tale of One City in the Dark}. New York: Little and Sons, 1998.}\\

\hspace{1.2cm}1. Herman Taylor, \emph{A Tale of One City in the Dark} (New York: Little and Sons, 1998), 77.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're forgetting the `\parindent` and also are abusing ``\\``. Can you tell what's the expected output?

Comment: Ah yes, \parindent. Ok, I've got it to work with \noindent. But why is this \\ "abuse"?

Comment: Paragraphs are ended by an empty line, not with ``\\``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primitive command `\hangindent` specifies that the first `\hangafter` lines are not indented (the default value of `\hangafter` is 1) and subsequent lines are indented from the left margin as requested by the argument to `\hangindent`.

This applies if both `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` are positive, different effects can be obtained when one or both are negative.

The normal indentation is applied anyway, so if you want that the text starts at the left margin you need `\noindent`:

```
\noindent\hangindent=1.2cm
Taylor, Herman. \emph{A Tale of One City in the Dark}. New York: Little and Sons, 1998.
```

Note that there's no argument. Moreover `\\` should *never* be used to end a paragraph.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\hangindent1.2cm
Taylor, Herman. \emph{A Tale of One City in the Dark}. New York: Little and Sons, 1998.

\noindent
\hspace{1.2cm}1. Herman Taylor, \emph{A Tale of One City in the Dark} (New York: Little and Sons, 1998), 77.

\end{document}
```

I use `showframe` just to show the margins. Note that setting `\hangindent` is incompatible with LaTeX list environments.

[image]